# Spring MVC Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map

Tags: java, spring

I want to send "Value" from one of the Radio Buttons to SpringMVC, but I watch the problem where I didn't expect.
And I has read similar answers on my topic, but I hasn't found the answer on my question
HTML:

```
 <form action="addRadio"  method="post" >

            <input type="radio" name="rbn" id="rbn" value="Red"/>Red
            <input type="radio" name="rbn"  value="White"/>White
            <input type="radio" name="rbn"  value="Blue"/>Blue
            <input type="radio" name="rbn"  value="Yellow"/>Yellow

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>
```

Try recieve in Java:

```
@Controller
public class testController {
@RequestMapping(name = "/test", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView seeTest(){
    ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
    m.setViewName("addFabric/testRadio");
    return m;
}
@RequestMapping(name = "/addRadio", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView add(@RequestParam(value = "rbn", required = false) String name){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    System.out.println("Type Radio: "+name);
    modelAndView.setViewName("index");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

}
And I recieve this mistake:

```
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean     with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
 defined in class path resource   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map '/test' method 
    public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView margo.controller.add.testController.seeTest()
    to {[],methods=[GET || POST]}: There is already 'addTestController' bean method
    public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView margo.controller.add.addTestController.add(java.lang.String) mapped.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1589) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: read the exception. as exceptions go, that's a pretty readable one, and tells you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dunni [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741496/1479414), there is another controller `addTestController` where you have duplicated methods.

Additionally you should remove `RequestMethod.POST` from `seeTest()` method, and remove `RequestMethod.GET` from `add(...)`:

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView seeTest(){ ... }

@RequestMapping(name = "/addRadio", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView add(@RequestParam(value = "rbn", required = false) String name){ ... }
```

That's because your form send data using `POST` method, so no need for declaring `GET` resource for `/addRadio`. In the same time for just retrieving page with form `GET` method should be used.

Answer (score 3):

You already mapped the method `add` in the class `addTestController` to the path `/test`. So change either the path in `addTestController` or in `testController`. Also you might want to stick to Java naming conventions and start class names with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a @RequestBody to seeTest() method